# What are the variables in this block of code for this textbox?

Tags: vb.net

Can someone tell me the different variables in this block of code, if it is also possible know details of the process that would also be great:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
   If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 OrElse e.KeyChar = " ") OrElse (e.KeyChar >= "A" AndAlso e.KeyChar <= "z")) Then
        e.Handled = True
        CType(sender, TextBox).Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This event handler handles the KeyPress event of a Textbox. See this piece of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for further information and also on the parameters provided.
The event is commonly used to handle specific user input in a special way. In this case, the code is used to filter user input and clear the textbox once a a user enters a character other than ASCII 8, a space or a letter in the range from A-Z (both upper and lower case).
In order to accomplish this, the character that has been entered by the user (e.KeyChar) is compared with the range. If the condition is met, e.Handled is set in order to circumvent that the character is processed as usual (e.g. added to the textbox content).
Also, the textbox is cleared by casting the sender parameter that contains the *sender* of the event to type of Textbox and calling the Clear method. The cast is necessary because the sender parameter is of the more general type Control that does not provide the Clear method.